# cordova iosRTC complie error

Tags: ios, swift, cordova

I am using cordova iosRTC plugin for webRTC support in ios.I am following [this link](https://github.com/eface2face/cordova-plugin-iosrtc/blob/master/docs/Building.md) to use iosRTC plugin.But When i am executing "cordova  build ios" command its giving build failed with following error

> The following build commands failed:

```
CompileSwift normal i386 /Users/laxman/Desktop/rahul/curetest/platforms/ios/curespring/Plugins/cordova-plugin-iosrtc/iosrtcPlugin.swift
CompileSwift normal i386 /Users/laxman/Desktop/rahul/curetest/platforms/ios/curespring/Plugins/cordova-plugin-iosrtc/PluginRTCTypes.swift
CompileSwiftSources normal i386 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
```

(3 failures)

> Error code 65 for command:
>   xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/laxman/Desktop/rahul/curetest/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,curespring.xcodeproj,ARCHS=i386,-target,curespring,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,build,VALID_ARCHS=i386,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/laxman/Desktop/rahul/curetest/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/laxman/Desktop/rahul/curetest/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
>   ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /Users/laxman/Desktop/rahul/curetest/platforms/ios/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
>   You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
>   Error: /Users/laxman/Desktop/rahul/curetest/platforms/ios/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
>       at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:139:23)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
>       at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)

But when i excute ".xcodeproj" file using xcode 6.3.1 its not giving build error and program is running fine in "i5s" device but still its not supporting webRTC . please suggest me what to do.